# Время в датафрейме

Tags: python

Как в датафрейме разделить столбец Date из `2022-02-17 16:39:00`,
чтобы получились столбцы Date `2022-02-17` и  Time`16:39`, а также отдельно выделить время по другому столбцу с Time `23:39:10.799900` (с доли секундами), чтобы получить Time `23:39`.

Comment: какой исходный тип данных и какие типы данных вы хотите получить в резульате?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [128]: df
Out[128]:
                         Date
0  2022-02-17 23:39:10.799900

In [129]: df[["Date", "Time"]] = df["Date"].str.split(expand=True)

In [130]: df
Out[130]:
         Date             Time
0  2022-02-17  23:39:10.799900

In [131]: df["Time_2"] = df["Time"].str.replace(r":[^:]*$", "", regex=True)

In [132]: df
Out[132]:
         Date             Time Time_2
0  2022-02-17  23:39:10.799900  23:39

In [133]: df.dtypes
Out[133]:
Date      object
Time      object
Time_2    object
dtype: object
```